# Select sub-folders if any

Tags: vb.net, outlook, directory

I want to verify if sub-folders exists, then select those sub-folders.

I select a folder with `getDefaultfolder`, like:

```
' INBOX 
siFolder = Ctype(ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox), Outlook.Folder)
' SENT ITEMS 
siFolder = Ctype(ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail), Outlook.Folder)
etc ... 

Where ... 
app = New Outlook.Application()
ns = app.Session
```

It works fine, but I can't see if there are existing sub-folders, and I don't know how to select them.

Comment: Stack Overflow has an [official English-only policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) (that, sadly, [is not documented in the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40271/shouldnt-the-english-only-policy-be-mentioned-in-the-faq)).

Comment: You can follow the French Stackoveflow proposal on Area51 to promote this site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12692/stack-overflow-in-french

Comment: What is your goal and why do you need to select folders? You can use Folders.Count to get a count of folders. If the answer is > 0 then there are subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub  CreateNewFolder()
        Dim oApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
        Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Dim InboxFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
        Dim customFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Try
            For i = 1 To InboxFolder.Folders.Count
                If InboxFolder.Folders.Item(i).Name = "Vellaichamy" Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
            customFolder = InboxFolder.Folders.Add("Vellaichamy", Outlook _
           .OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
            InboxFolder.Folders("Vellaichamy").Display()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("The following error occurred: " & ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Clean up.
            oApp = Nothing
            oNS = Nothing
            InboxFolder = Nothing
            customFolder = Nothing
        End Try
    End Sub
```